# How to create effect of divs floating over image with css and js/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I create the effect of divs or sections of pages floating (for lack of a better description) over images?

The effects I'm interested in are showcased here: 
http://www.thedailybeast.com/newsweek/2013/08/30/on-syria-go-big-or-stay-home.html
http://www.kitkat.com/

Links to libraries, jsfiddle examples, or tutorials would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are invited to read http://stackoverflow.com/help.

Comment: can you provide more clarity to your requirement. Also of the showcased example links, what needs to be achieved?

Comment: Are you refferring to the text boxes that are over the images in those links?

Comment: Which effect?  Floating a div over an image, like a... background image?

Answer (score 3):

Put background on div like this, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/LK9H2/)

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="innerdiv">

  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: url(../images/myimage.png) center no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
}
.innerdiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can see what they did by doing inspection on the page, but to directly answer your question, they are using a framework for the most part, however they did some extra stuff.

They are using Twitter Bootstrap for their layout.  Below is a very rough copy of what they did.

http://jsbin.com/EjeDiPI/1/