# Howto set a div above a background-image

Tags: css, html

i'm trying to achieve this: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zm1qssd3299uat/Social-Bottom.jpg

I want a content div that stands above the background div like the image above.

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>VisionBeat DJ's Australia</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/nav.js"></script>
    <LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="./favicon.ico">
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family:"bold";
            src: url('./fonts/bold.ttf');
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family:"sbold";
            src: url('./fonts/sbold.ttf');
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family:"regular";
            src: url('./fonts/regular.ttf');
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family:"light";
            src: url('./fonts/light.ttf');
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family:"elight";
            src: url('./fonts/elight.ttf');
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow:auto;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border:0;
            font-family:'regular', sans-serif;
        }
        #bg1 {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: url(./images/backgrounds/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            z-index:0;
        }
        #bg2 {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: url(./images/backgrounds/2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            z-index:1;
        }
        #bg3 {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: url(./images/backgrounds/3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            z-index:2;
        }
        h1 {
            font-family:'bold', sans-serif;
            font-weight:700;
            color:#ecf0f1
        }
        h2 {
            font-family:'sbold', sans-serif;
            font-weight:600;
            color:#ecf0f1
        }
        p1 {
            font-family:'regular', sans-serif;
            font-weight:400;
            color:#ecf0f1
        }
        p2 {
            font-family:'light', sans-serif;
            font-weight:300;
            color:#ecf0f1
        }
        a {
            font-family:'elight', sans-serif;
            font-weight:300;
            color:#ecf0f1;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            text-decoration:none
        }
        a:hover {
            font-family:'elight', sans-serif;
            font-weight:200;
            color:#ecf0f1;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            right:0;
        }
        nav {
            color:rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.5);
            font-size:1.2em;
            font-weight:300;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            transition: border-color 0.5s ease;
            border-top:1.5px solid;
            border-color:rgba(45, 45, 45, 0);
        }
        nav a {
            transition: border-color 0.5s ease;
            border-top:1.5px solid;
            border-color:rgba(45, 45, 45, 0);
        }
        nav a:hover {
            border-color: rgba(236, 240, 241, 0.9)
        }
        #floater {
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            height:50%;
            margin-bottom:-100px;
            width:1px;
        }
        #centered {
            position:relative;
            clear:left;
            height:250px;
        }
        #centerfit {
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            max-height: 250px;
        }
        #sticky_navigation_wrapper {
            width:100%;
            height:30px;
        }
        #sticky_navigation {
            width:100%;
            height:32px;
            background-color:rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.75);
            text-align:center;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="bg1">
        <div id="floater"></div>
        <div id="centered">
            <div id="centerfit">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="VisionBeat Logo">
            </div>
            <div id="sticky_navigation_wrapper">
                <div id="sticky_navigation">
                    <nav>
                        <a href="#Social">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Social&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                        <a href="#Contact">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                        <a href="/">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                        <a href="#Events">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Events&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                        <a href="#Pricing">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pricing&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section id="Social"></section>
    <div id="bg2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Never use &nbsp; for spacing please. Use CSS padding/margin or other methods.

Comment: Check out my answer on same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658032/how-to-create-effect-of-divs-floating-over-image-with-css-and-js-jquery/18658196#18658196).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set the background image on the body tag and make sure to use CSS positioning on the elements you set a `z-index` for. 
I guess you are facing the problem, that your content div is not above the background image. Try to set the positioning for the content div absolute and make sure to set the background image on the body tag.